# How to selectively filter based on various paramters value

Tags: java, design-patterns

I work for an investment bank and we need to deal with Market and Instruments. So in my programming question I will be using those words to make the question more clear.

I have been trying to build an interface and its implementation of  **ReferenceData**  whose tasks are:

- getAllInstruments()
- getAllInstrumentsForAMarket(final String market)
- getInstrumentsFromAllMarketOfAnISIN(final String isin)
- getInstrumentFromAMarketAndISIN(final String market, final String isin)

Including above there will be other combination of parameters and will involve other parameters like instrument type (Bond, future etc.).

The above design will lead to make a parameter combination as and when new type of query parameter is taken into account in future which is I believe a bad design.

I followed up with Interpreter pattern as discussed by **Joshua Kerievsky's Refactoring To Patterns** but I am stuck with two problems:

- How to deal with null values in the parameters, like somebody might be using method ***getInstrumentFromAMarketAndISIN(final String market, final String isin)*** and passing null value in market.
  It is to be considered as a valid query which should then be a case of ***getInstrumentsFromAllMarketOfAnISIN(final String isin)***.
- I do not want to have the client deal with if else checks of parameters and then call the methods, because these are utility methods and will be called from plenty of places, which will lead to null checks all over the client code everywhere. 
  Instead the implementation of **ReferenceData** should be able to handle it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue with having a null value and why can't the code you're writing perform a null check?

Comment: Also, why wouldn't you implement getInstrumentsFromAllMarketOfAnISIN(final String isin) as a call to getInstrumentFromAMarketAndISIN(null, isin);

Seems like to do otherwise is unnecessary code duplication.

Comment: @iheanyi: 1st question- because as I said there could be more parameters. So lets saty there is a third method getAllInstrumentsOfMarketPlusIsinAndType(final String market, final String isin, final String type)..then I will have to do null checks for each of them or even combinations and based on the parameter(s) which is/are null I will have to return the query result.. I hope you get it.

Comment: @iheanyi: 2nd question: because I want to expose the getInstrumentsFromAllMarketOfAnISIN(final String isin). As the interface is a kind of ReferenceData finder so this is also a valid work proposed by its contract.

Comment: It is quite similar to Interpreter Pattern as discussed in Refactoring to Patterns, but I am stuck with the issues I mentioned.

Comment: Again, you still seem to want to do way more work than you need. You can expose as many methods as you want. Lets say you have a maximum of 5 parameters. All of your methods will call the 5 parameter one with nulls in the appropriate place. Then, all you have to do is perform 5 null checks in that one function. Almost all query languages support nulls, so I don't see why you'd need to do any combination null checks.

Comment: Let's say I have three parameters, two are null, one has a value.

I'd build my query one parameter at a time. "Select instruments from database where "

parameter 0 is null, skip adding to query.
parameter 1 is null, skip adding to query.
parameter 2 is not null, add to query "param2 = " value-supplied-by-user.

A simple flag lets you know whether you need to add an "AND" after you add a parameter to the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69615/discussion-between-iheanyi-and-dipesh-gupta).

Comment: sure, see my comments in the chat.

Comment: You didn't respond any further. Does that mean what I said made sense?